# Based on a forms input value, how 2 generate selections 4 a drop down menu w row/record data from a database that will prefill a form when selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm trying to figure out a way to pre fill a form with data with past form information submitted in the past.

I have a form and a database.  In my form I have a input named `email` that holds the pre-loaded default value of logged in member's email address that is read-only.

**PIC**

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2iubb4j.jpg

How can I generate a selection under a drop down menu that when selected will pre-fill the form with row/record data from my database?

and how can I generate only the records that match the forms input value 'email' to the records with the same value under the 'email' column in the database?

I've been at it for weeks now and can not seem to find any sense of direction on how to achieve this.  Can't really find any tutorials site, video, sample code or anything close on how to make this possible.  Any help would be great...thanks for your help in advance.

---

**FORM**

```
</header>

<body>

<form action="/demoform/contact_form.php" class="well" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" novalidate="">

<big>LOAD PAST ORDERS:</big>
<select id="extrafield1" name="extrafield1">
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
 <option value="xxx">SAMPLE SELECTION</option>
</select>

</br>

<input type="text" required id="mile" name="mile" placeholder="Miles"/>

</br>

<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text" value="demo@gmail.com" readonly="readonly"/>

</br>

<input id="name" name="itemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME 1" required="" type="text" />

</br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset" />


<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>


</body>


</html>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

if (isset($_POST['itemname'])){
    $itm = $_POST['itemname'];
}
else {
  $itm = '';
}



if($_POST['mile']){
    $mi = $_POST['mile'];
}else{
    echo "Miles not received";
    exit;
}



if($_POST['email']){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}else{
    echo "email not received";
    exit;
}




$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (itemname, mile, email) 
        VALUES ('$itm', '$mi', '$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
```

---

***UPDATE: closest thing below so far...but wont work...not sure it covers the matching the email values portion...thanks anyways 'edcoder'***

```
<select id="extrafield1" name="extrafield1">
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<?php
$query='select * from tablename';
$res=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row['feildname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['feildname']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: you are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions. That is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're almost there.

Try this.

```
<select id="extrafield1" name="extrafield1">
    <option value="">Please select...</option> 
    <?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query="select * from tablename WHERE email={$_POST['email']}";
    $res=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['fieldname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['fieldname']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: did'nt generate any selections...thanks for you help

Comment: @BestDayEver2015 Did you finally fix this or do you still need help?

Comment: Hey thanks I really appreciate your time and effort...i know you get it. Tried using your above code...but its not working.  I feel like from looking at your code it looks like it should work but I cant figure out why it doesn't.  So i built another demo database and form and tried plugging in your above code and nothing.  Here's a link to every bit of code I'm using... http://codeviewer.org/view/code:49b7       And heres a pic of the database and a mock up of what im trying to achieve...   http://oi61.tinypic.com/264ks5u.jpg